# Pass form data from jade in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I've got the following small express.js app and the corresponding .jade file. Server is running without errors but when I submit the button, nothing happens. I would expect that the app.post(...) is called, but it is not.

Could someone point me to the mistake?

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');

var app = express();


var port = process.env.PORT || 9250;
var host = process.env.HOST || "127.0.0.1";

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(
  port,
  host,
  function() {
   console.log("Server listening to %s:%d within %s environment",
     host, port, app.get('env'));
  });


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);

app.use( bodyParser.json() ); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(app.get('views') + '/index.html')
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {

 res.render('home.jade');
});

app.post('/claim', function(req, res) {
 console.log('called');
 res.redirect('/');
});
```

```html
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Hello

  body
    h1 Welcome
    p Description

    form(action="/claim", method="post")
    label Input something
    br
    input(type="text", name="address", size=50)
    br
    input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is indentation : Jade doesn't understand your `input` is included in `form`.

Try this, it works for me :

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Hello

body
  h1 Welcome
  p Description

  form(action="/claim", method="post")
    label Input something
    br
    input(type="text", name="address", size=50)
    br
    input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

Comment: Great, the indentations were the problem. Thanks! It works fine now!